# HTML escaping in GridX

Tags: javascript, dojo, escaping, dojo.gridx

Does **[GridX](http://oria.github.io/gridx/)** support HTML escaping for texts in cells?

I've failed to find the attribute like `escapeHTMLInData` from `dojox.grid.DataGrid`.

Does GridX has built-in HTML escaping, or one need to write a module for that, evt. manually escape the text fields before setting them in grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridX, from version 1.3, has build-in HTML escaping, which is activated by parameter `encode: true` to the grid structure:

```
var structure = [
    { id: 'name', field: 'name', name: 'Name', encode: true},
    { id: 'city', field: 'city', name: 'City', encode: true},
    { id: 'score', field: 'score', name: 'Score}
];

var grid = Grid({
      id: 'grid',
      cacheClass: Cache,
      store: store,
      structure: structure
});
```